# Responsive Webdesign - Header

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Before i shoot my question and someone shoots me after:

I most likely searched the entire web to solve my problem, as i'm here...you will understand that my problem isn't solved by now...

I'm so frustrated cause...there is not 1 solution but many! All of them have pro's & con's. I'm a person who always looks for logic...and we all know in webdeveloping, there is not much or none at all.

I'm looking for something simple, very simple. - A header image that is responsive. I've inspected many many websites that are a great example but they ALL use something different. From Background-size:contain to table-cells. Let me shut up now and explain my frustration.

This is what i would like to get:

[Link 3](http://bellroy.com/pages/live-life-outside/) It doesn't have to be a video..just a image...

I would like a header that uses a background-image where i can place text on (Centered horizontaly & vertical) top of the background image. I also would like the image to be responsive. I achieved something close but i don't think i'm doing it the right way cause i'm using a fixed height for my image. I don't find another solution cause if i don't put a height, nothing shows up.

This is what i have:

[My Website](http://www.md-esign.be)

I hope i make myself clear...
Can someone help me! Please??? Pretty please???

Comment: are you trying to animate background-images?

Comment: No, i want a background-image for my header that is responsive without having to set a fixed height for the image.

Comment: Can you explain in what way your background image to be reponsive

Comment: I want my header to scale automaticly to the width of the browser at any time.

Comment: And the problem is, i can set width:100%, thats ok, but when i set  height:250px (height of image) its always scaling on that fixed height.

Comment: How about using it as a background image in a div

Comment: That is what im doing at the moment. But if you dont set a height for the div, nothing will show up. So when im setting a height, its fixed...and thats the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gszzapsd/6/. Is this how you want the header to function when you reduce the size of the screen? The bellroy.com website which you've quoted, they are actually using an image with 100% width and auto height and then the text which says `LIVE LIFE OUTSIDE` is positioned absolutely over it. This is how their code of that particular section looks like:

```
<div id="landingCover" class="snow">
      <img src="http://assets.bellroy.com/skin/frontend/default/bellroy/images/elements/snow/cover.1405318855.jpg" alt="" class="hidden-image" width="1348">
      <div class="landing-fixed-header skrollable skrollable-between" data-0="top:0%; opacity:1" data-top-bottom="top:15%; opacity:0" style="top: 0%; opacity: 1;">
        <h1>LIVE LIFE OUTSIDE</h1>
        <h2>EXTRA WALLET PROTECTION FOR ALL WEATHER CONDITIONS</h2>
      </div>
</div>
```

Nevertheless, if you'd like the background-image of your header div to scale based on the size of the browser window, please add these styles to the CSS of `#page_title` on your website:

```
#page_title {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thx for this but what about the height? Height:auto doesnt show the header. So setting the height of the img to pxs makes it fixed again. And i dont like fixed heights in responsive design...

Comment: If you'd like the height to be auto then you can add some padding to the `#page_title` div. Simply remove the `min-height: 240px` style which you've currently added to the CSS of `#page_title` and add these styles to it:

`#page_title { padding: 10%; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain; background-position: center; }`. You can simply add padding in percentages to a `<div>` if you don't want to assign it a fixed height in responsive design.